# Object Required Error Message. How to get all NotesItem names for a NotesDocument?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, foreach, lotus-notes

Hi am very new to VBA and LotusNotes but I'm trying to get all the names of NotesItem within a NotesDocument.

I saw a few examples online but they did not seem to work for me as I am getting an "Object Required" error message. Below are the lines of code that I'm using to try to get all the names of items and concatenate them to a string.

```
Set domtdoc = domdocs.GetFirstDocument
Dim Item As NotesItem
Dim itemNames As String
itemNames = ""
For Each Item In domtdoc.Items
   itemNames = itemNames + (Item.Name) + ", "
Next Item
```

Can someone please give me some advice on what I may be doing wrong or suggest an alternative way? I also tried with a "Forall" loop but that wouldn't even compile as I seen in this example: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/0f178da5ad5670ea8525642e00765a31?OpenDocument

Ok, I've updated below code using "Forall"

```
Set domtdoc = domdocs.GetFirstDocument
Dim itemNames As String
Forall i In domtdoc.Items
  itemNames = itemNames + i.Name + ", "
End Forall
```

And I get the following error message

Compile Error: 
Expected: End of statement

Thanks

Comment: As per Knut's comment below, forall is not valid in VBA. Sorry... I forgot about that. Anyhow, in your original version add two tests before the for each loop - for If domtdocs Is Nothing, and for If domtdocs.Items is Nothing, printing an error message if either one of them hits. It seems like you're probably not actually getting access to the Notes document. The actual problen might be occurring before you even get to this code.

Comment: Yes, it seemed to work using alternative suggested by Knut's. Thanks for the help as well!

Comment: Good to hear that it worked.  (Since it worked, it would be courteous of you to upvote and accept Knut's answer!)

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to this. How do I upvote/accept Knut's answer as he left it in a comment?

Comment: Ah, okay. I see that now. It was Knut's comment on Thomas' answer. A team effort then! :-)  But you can actually upvote a comment.  They don't make it obvious, and I'm not sure how much it counts for, but it can be done by hovering your mouse cursor over the left hand edge of the comment, at which point an up-arrow appears and you can click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use forall, not for each
This should work

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim itemNames as String
'...set value of doc...
Forall i In doc.Items
  itemNames = itemNames + i.Name + ", "
End Forall
```

[image]

Comment: thnks...but I originally tried it using forall but I get a different error. Compile Error: Expected: end of statement. Not sure why

Comment: Please update the question to show the version of the code with the forall so we can help you find the error in your syntax.

Comment: I've updated but still get issue. Both the "Forall i In domtdoc.Items" and "End Forall" lines are actually highlighted in red text too.

Comment: You mentioned VBA in your question, I got the impression that you are working in Notes? I updated my answer with a screenshot, working code for use in Notes.

Comment: Forall is not available in Excel VBA. The equivalent is For Each there. If this doesn't work then `For i=0 To ubound(arrayItems)` should work.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the tip. Using Excel VBA it did not seem to allow Forall so I used the For i=0 to Uboud(array) as you suggested and it worked!

Comment: @ThomasAdrian yes, I was working in Excel, sorry should have been more specific I guess. Being new to VBA I was unaware that some things may be avaialbe/unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

So what finally worked for me was the following using VBA in Excel which was suggested in the comments. Thank you guys, I will keep in mind the alternative ways to do the same.

```
Set domtdoc = domdocs.GetFirstDocument
Dim itemNames As String
Dim Item As Integer

For Item = LBound(domtdoc.Items) To UBound(domtdoc.Items)
  itemNames = itemNames + domtdoc.Items(Item) + ", "
Next Item
```